# Question about algebraic geometry terminology in Borel's "Linear Algebraic Groups"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to understand some results in Borel's book "Linear Algebraic Groups" about algebraic groups defined over non-algebraically closed fields, and I don't understand part of his terminology (probably because he is using archaic language instead of schemes).

Let $k$ be a field and let $G$ be a linear algebraic group defined over $k$.  In for instance Chapter 20 Borel makes a distinction between a subgroup $H$ of $G$ being "defined over $k$" and being "$k$-closed".  What does this mean?

Comment: Welcome! From a quick search, this might be answered by §AG.11.4 in the book (page 23 in the 2nd edition).

Comment: If [@BCnrd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3927/bcnrd) were still an active member here, he would caution you not to learn algebraic geometry from Borel (or Springer).  They are wonderful references for the facts about smooth groups, but they handle non-smoothness poorly.  The distinction here is relevant when we consider things like the intersection of two different maximal in $\operatorname{SL}_2$ when $p = 2$; this intersection is a non-smooth subgroup.  If I recall correctly, Borel describes this by saying that the intersection is $k$-closed but not defined over $k$.

Comment: @LSpice: Ah, that makes sense.  Is there a better place to learn the structure of isotropic reductive groups over fields that aren't algebraically closed?  Every English-language source I've consulted eventually punts to Borel or Springer for important details.

Comment: @BCnrd's [Pseudo-reductive groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316092439) is a thorough but daunting reference; I found Milne's [Algebraic groups](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/iag.html) very accessible.  I should say very carefully that Borel and Springer are still *excellent* references for the structure theory; they just don't handle algebraic-geometry subtleties in a modern way.  But, if you are just starting to learn, then you might as well learn the modern way, and I would probably recommend Milne for that—correct without too-heavy pre-requisites.

Comment: @LSpice: Gotta admit that I'm scared of "Pseudo-reductive groups".  I have Milne on my desk, and for the stuff I need (in Chapter 25, section b) he just surveys things and says "For proofs, see Borel 1991, V.21 and Springer 1998, Chapter 15."

Comment: Probably PRG also frequently references Borel and Springer.  I do mean it when I say that these are excellent references (and I think Milne doesn't get into the reductive-group structure theory in that volume, though he does have [notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/RG.pdf)).  I learned from Borel and Springer myself, so I can't say what it's like to try to learn from Milne, but I do wish I'd read it earlier.  Perhaps the right thing to say is to do as you're doing, and read Milne but be prepared to refer to B/S as needed.

Comment: I have a somewhat unusual short-term goal in that I need a sequence of very specific facts for a paper I'm writing on something else, so I'm trying to become enough of a semi-expert that I can quote results fluently without necessarily making the massive time investment needed to become a real expert.  I'm totally fine with the story over algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$, and until now that was enough...

Comment: You can find my contact information in my [profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2383/lspice?tab=profile).  I'm no expert in structure theory, but I have pieced together some of it from long use.  Feel free to e-mail me if a few focussed questions might be more helpful than a general-purpose discussion here.

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks for the offer!  I need to think some more, but I might take you up on it.

Comment: Milne's book is an excellent one, but if you want a quick introduction to the subject, I would try Waterhouse's "Introduction to Affine Group Schemes". Having grasped the basics of the subject, then I would consult Borel just for the references of the results needed. On the other hand, the bibles from a modern point of view might be SGA 3 and Demazure-Gabriel's "Groupes algébriques", if you understand French.